# Issues with upgrading Hibernate 3 to hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate, migration, hibernate-4.x, hibernate3

I have been upgrading my project from Hibernate 3.x version to Hibernate 4.1.4. Now I have a peculiar problem with me.

After placing all the required JARs and referring them on the classpath, builing `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException`

This class was present in hibernate3.jar earlier. Now, Its in Hibernate-core. Still not able to figure out why its saying so..

I deleted the earlier deployments and deployed this again. Verified Hibernate 4 jars being present there. Still I get this error when I start server.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: are you using maven? Have you updated the manifest as well?

Comment: Open .classpath file and see which libraries its referring?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help people. The issue was due to reference of `hibernate3.jar` in an ant build file. Had to change it to `hibernate*.jar` which solved the problem.